# Is there equivalent of AIDL on other platforms (iOS, Blackberry, Windows Mobile)

Tags: ios, windows-phone-7, blackberry, windows-mobile, aidl

Is there equivalent of [Android Interface Definition Language](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) (AIDL) on BlackBerry mobile?

We have developed an Android application using AIDL, and we would like to develop the same application on BlackBerry, iPhone and Windows Mobile.

Is there any equivalent of AIDL available on these platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like it on Blackberry < 10, as far as I know. Blackberry 10 is compatible with Android (emulates Android applications natively).

iOS is also very different, the applications are much more separated than Android applications. There is no concept of background services, so there is also no concept of interface language.

I don't know anything about Windows Mobile.